# Read and list large number of files from multiple folders in c#

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0, system.io.file, system.io.directory

I want to read large number of files which spans across multiple folders in a network drive.

I have approximately 20 folders, each folder has 50 sub folders and each sub folder has approximately 400 json files. I need to read one keyword in json file and if then if the data is good then I need to parse the file. From all these files I may need to parse only 300 files a day, but I need to go through each file to find if it's good or not.

I have tried reading files fro each folder using,

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles
```

But it takes a long time. What is the bes way to handle this situation?
Is there a better way to some powershell script or Pearl etc to traverse through all folders and get paths of all good files in a list as text file and I can read only those good files?

My program is in c#

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles` returns the _file names_ that it finds. How is that slow? What code are you using to read the file _contents_?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a large number of files quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205898/reading-a-large-number-of-files-quickly)

Comment: Files are on a network share and one parent folder has around 700K files in it including ~ 3000 sub directories. If I do EnumerateFiles in the main directory then it takes very long time.

Comment: There is no faster way of obtaining file names from the file system than `Directory.EnumerateFiles` (and variations). Trying to read that many folders/files _across a network_ will always be slow, regardless of the programming language you use. The better way to fix this is to think like an engineer and see how you can optimize the layout of your folders so you don't need do do a complete file scan.

Comment: I can't change the file structure here, it exists in the system for many years and it can't be changed now. Only option for me to read the files in a better way.